# Call to undefined function is_bool()

Tags: php, undefined

My dev server is currently running PHP 5.3.29.  When trying to run the `is_bool()` function on a variable, I receive the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_​bool() in...

Running `echo function_exists("is_bool");` returns true.

Running the commands on my local machine with 5.3.28 yield the same results, but works correctly on my coworker's local machine running 5.5.14.

Although [the official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-bool.php) says that this function is available in PHP 4 and 5, is there an issue with my PHP versions preventing me from using this function?  This is also happening with `is_int()`, `is_null()`, etc.

```
<?php

$Value = "random";  // Also tried integers and booleans

echo function_exists("is_bool");  // prints 1

echo is_​bool($Value) ? "true" : "false";  // Fatal error
```

Comment: Show sample code where error occurs.

Comment: @u_mulder Added to the original question, but that's all there is to it.  This is in a completely separate test file all by itself.

Comment: You are having a none breaking space before bool. Please copy is_bool from here and paste it in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was about to copy&paste your code snippet from above into http://3v4l.org/ to prove you wrong ;) – and syntax highlighting there shows, that you have an invisible character between `is_` and `bool` (in the line you marked with the `// Fatal error` comment).

Pasting it into Notepad++ and viewing it in Hex mode shows that the byte sequence is `e2 80 8b`, and that is the UTF8-encoded version of a [zero width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) character.

So just re-type it completely (presumably that has gotten in there by copy&pasting it from somewhere, where the output was formatted in some way) – and it should work fine …

Comment: No idea how that got it in there, especially considering it was also in the `is_int()` and `is_null()` functions too.